# Unrecognized HTTP request to remote js library from my site

Tags: magento2.3, http-request

My site has a HTTP request being made to get this remote js library - https://r1-t.trackedlink.net/_dmpt.min.js and I do not know why? Can anyone help me with what this is?
Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tracking script, that launched from `Dotdigitalgroup_Email` module, which is enabled by default and includes in Magento package.

You may have experienced error by loading this script because you have enabled uBlock or other ad-block browser extension. For resolving this, try to whitelist your website in extension options.

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12828#issuecomment-353120645

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Also, I am no more using this extension so how can I remove this tracking request?

Comment: @shivam you can simply disable this module if you not going to use it: 

`php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email --clear-static-content`

Comment: The module is actually disabled for a long time still the site is making that particular HTTP request.
Anyway, I will try to figure something out. Thank you so much for your help though.
Have a great day.